# The SDK directory does not exist Travis CI

Tags: travis-ci

I have this .travis.yml file, but I am constantly getting this error when building:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory '/home/travis/build/Me/MyProject/C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' does not exist.
```

My .travis.yml

```
language: android
before_install:
- chmod +x gradlew
script: 
- ./gradlew clean assembleDebug
install:
 - true
 - chmod +x ./gradlew; ls -l gradlew; ./gradlew wrapper -v
android:

components:
# Uncomment the lines below if you want to
# use the latest revision of Android SDK Tools
# - platform-tools
# - tools

# The BuildTools version used by your project
- build-tools-23.0.3

# The SDK version used to compile your project
- android-23

# Additional components
- extra-google-google_play_services
- extra-google-m2repository
- extra-android-m2repository
- addon-google_apis-google-23

# Specify at least one system image,
# if you need to run emulator(s) during your tests
- sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23
- sys-img-x86-android-17
```

I cannot find anything on google about it, so I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not commit your local.properties file into your repository.